# Fetching images of AIMAGE_FORMAT_JPEG fails

Tags: android, c++, image, android-ndk

When fetching images:

```
assert(AIMAGE_FORMAT_JPEG == src_format, "Failed to get format");
AImage_getHeight(image, &height);
AImage_getWidth(image, &width);
AImage_getPlaneData(image, 0, &pixel, &y_len);

AImage_getPlaneRowStride(image, 0, &stride);
AImage_getPlanePixelStride(image, 0, &pixel_stride);
```

Note, that the last 2 commands return `AMEDIA_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED` for that format - see [docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___media.html#ga0b2f54f6d5f347af84bce90dd6da27f1).

---

Now writing on the buffer:

```
uint8_t *out = buf.data;
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    const uint8_t *pY = pixel + width*3*y;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        out[x*3 + 0] = pY[x*3 + 0];
        out[x*3 + 1] = pY[x*3 + 1];
        out[x*3 + 2] = pY[x*3 + 2];
    }
    out += width*3;
}
```

the app crashes after start up very quickly. The `logcat` does not output something meaningful to me - at least not readable. Any thoughts on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getPlaneData()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/ndk/NdkImage.cpp#336) for JPEG gives you the undecoded buffer. You can see that the returned size is much smaller than `width*height*3`.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that too. So does it mean I have to take care of the decoding myself?

Comment: Yes, if you want RGB it, then you can use the equivalent of `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`. You can also have YUV data. Note that even though there is libjpeg.so in the system/libs folder, you should not use it, but rather embed libjpeg in your app.